# Adding new site language in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, multilingual

Is it possible to control site languages from django admin?
if we need new language we should add in settings.py like that:
settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ("ru", _("Russian")),
    ("en", _("English"))
)
```

But is there any way to allow admin to add new supported language using django admin panel?